# Conflict on answering same question about mentioning MOOC courses

Tags: discussion, answers

The answer of this question: [mentioning MOOC's I took in my scholarship application](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/20106/mentioning-moocs-i-took-in-my-scholarship-application)

> Yes! Why not? It shows that you go beyond what is required of you, and you have a genuine interest in learning. I always list certificates from MOOCs.

The answer of this question: [Can I include the completion of Udacity and Coursera classes I have attended in an academic CV?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/can-i-include-the-completion-of-udacity-and-coursera-classes-i-have-attended-in)

> No. Specific coursework (whether formal or informal, online or in-person) does not belong in an academic CV.

Of course, the first one doesn't mention about CV, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no conflict. You can mention things in an essay or application that you would not put in an academic CV.

Comment: Essay? You mean SOP?

Comment: Not only statements of purpose, but any persuasive writing that might be associated with such processes.